# php - ajax issue - One Click Delay in Data Prepending/Appending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prepend

I'm trying to get data from user and insert it into database, then again fetch all new data from same database and prepend to content box. All is fine, i'm getting only wanted data. But when I write post and click submit button it insert data in database but don't prepend new data. But when i write again a new post and click submit, it prepend the "last post" means it is working with 1 click delay. I tried to check with `console.log`, i'm getting perfect data on first click as well as 2nd click. So what is the issue in this code which restricting it to add data on first time? ( i don't know the title of problem -_- so if anyone can correct, please do )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var post = $("#s-content").val();
    post = $.trim(post);
    if (post=="")
    {
        $("#status-warning").show(100);setTimeout(function(){$("#status-warning").hide(100)},3000);
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process/post.php",
            data:$("#post").serialize(),
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                var request = $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                    url:"process/getNewPost.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']."&token=".session_id(); ?>",
                    /*success:function(data){
                        $("#all-posts").prepend(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        }*/
                    });
                    request.done(function(check){
                        console.log(check);
                        $("#all-posts").prepend(check);
                    });

                /*var a=''; 
                a += '<div><li style="white-space:pre;">';
                a += $("#s-content").val();
                a += '</li></div>';
                $("#all-posts").prepend(check);*/
                $("#s-content").val("");
                $("#remove").remove();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problem, but your solution is needlessly complicated.

1. You don't need to make 2 ajax requests. You already have the variables available in javascript so you can use these to modify your `#all-posts` section in the `success` function of your first ajax call. Even if you don't have everything available, you should have `process/post.php` return it and not make a new request to the server.
2. You don't need to add session variables to your url. Just start the session in php and you will have them all available. Although this probably does not matter any more as the second ajax call is innecessary.

Comment: 2. That session variable and id are for "show" only. (To manipulate xD) :P :D
and
1. I want to grab data from another php file not the same one. Then how can i do all process in single ajax request? 
And the reason why i'm using another php file - When `User A` posted his post and meanwhile `User B` also posted something, i need to show both posts. So i can't get data from `process/post.php` because it will show only single post, I'll need to fetch all new data, that's why i used another php file.

Comment: @user3314428 Just include `process/getNewPost.php` at the end of `process/post.php`. If you store a timestamp in the session with the last update, you can get only the records added after that timestamp, regardless who posted them.

Comment: hmm nice idea.. yeah i'm storing timestamp in session variable. I'll try and will let you know.. Are you sure this will solve my main problem?